# How do I force a ViewController to present without the user pressing any buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When a function is called, I would like `SixthViewController` to be presented to the user without the user needing to press any buttons. I know how to present another `ViewController`by setting a button to "Show" another `ViewController`, but how can I programmatically force `SixthViewController` to present itself once the function is called?

Comment: You can call yourself `performSegue()`, or `presentViewController()`, etc.

Comment: can you tell something about your conditions? On that condition you can call @Larme's suggested methods

Comment: I don't think conditions was the right word to use to describe what I'm trying to do; I'm trying to trigger SixthViewController to present itself when a certain function is called.

Comment: are you using xibs? storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

you can present viewcontroller with this way:

```
let destVC = SixthViewController() 
self.present(destVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardNamehere", bundle: nil) 
let destVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerIdentifierhere" as! SixthViewController 
self.present(destVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

========================================================================

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using segues but **navigation controller** try this:

```
let destinationVC = SixthViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
```

If you just want to show it **without navigation controller**:

```
let destinationVC = SixthViewController()
    self.present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you are **using storyboard**:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let destVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SixthViewController" as! SixthViewController
self.present(destVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

just write down this function and also called it when u want to push or write down it in any function like func pushViewController  and called it self.pushViewController() that's it bro.

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let sixthViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SixthViewController") as! SixthViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(sixthViewController, animated: true)
```